Find and mark duplicates
Aim:
I need to detect duplicates, based on the colums name, postcode, street and housenumber - eventhough postcode, street and housenumber can be empty.
The record to keep (master) should be the one with the max number of rel_a. If it‘s the same for two or more records, the most recent date modified should win.
I need to mark the master to keep, along with the information if a record has duplicates and if so, how many and to which master.
An example of data as input:
id,name,postcode,street,housenr,nr_rel_a,nr_rel_b,date_modified
1,abc,1000,a,4,10,5,01-01-2020
2,abc,1000,a,4,7,5,01-01-2019
3,abc,,,,5,5,01-01-2009
4,d,2000,d,5,3,5,01-01-2020
5,efg,3000,c,6,22,5,01-01-2020
6,efg,3000,,,2,5,01-01-2009
7,h,4000,d,7,56,5,01-01-2018
8,ijk,5000,e,8,50,5,01-01-2019
9,ijk,5000,e,8,50,5,01-01-2018
10,ijk,5000,e,,5,5,01-01-2009

An example of data as I imagine the ideal output (including sums of the rel_a and rel_b which go from the dups to the master):
id,name,postcode,street,housenr,nr_rel_a,nr_rel_b,date_modified,keep,nr_Dup,category,referenceID,Master_nr_rel_a,Master_nr_rel_b
1,abc,1000,a,4,10,5,01-01-2020,FALSE,2,MasterDup,1,22,15
2,abc,1000,a,4,7,5,01-01-2019,TRUE,,Dup,1,,
3,abc,,,,5,5,01-01-2009,TRUE,,Dup,1,,
4,d,2000,d,5,3,5,01-01-2020,FALSE,0,Master,4,4,5
5,efg,3000,c,6,22,5,01-01-2020,FALSE,1,MasterDup,5,24,10
6,efg,3000,,,2,5,01-01-2009,TRUE,,Dup,5,,
7,h,4000,d,7,56,5,01-01-2018,FALSE,0,Master,7,56,5
8,ijk,5000,e,8,50,5,01-01-2019,FALSE,2,MasterDup,8,105,15
9,ijk,5000,e,8,50,5,01-01-2018,TRUE,,Dup,8,,
10,ijk,5000,e,,5,5,01-01-2009,TRUE,,Dup,8,,

I read through comments, which described marking duplicates but I am not able to make the adaptions to serve my case.
I like to believe when I sort the input list on a) nr_rel_a and b) date_modified I can use df.duplicated(keep='first') to mark the master.
I struggle with the detection when one or more fields which should be used as dup criteria are empty. I also struggle with adding the referenceID and the the very_nice_to_have additional information.
I would be grateful for a hint or possibly simple peace of code example to read for beginners.
The dataset is small (less than 20k records).

Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please edit your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the full text of any errors or tracebacks, all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a minimal reproducible example.

Thanks a lot Andrej for editing my question. So much better!

Thanks Woodford - I thought I tried to comply with the criteria as much as I could. I'll keep trying.

I'd create a unique_key column using name, name, postcode, street, and housenumber. But since postcode, street and housenumber can be null, I'd use ifnull on those to create a default value. Perhaps 'null' as a string. Then I'd use a qualify at the end to enforce the uniqueness based on nr_rel_a and date_modified sorting.
select
  id
, name
, postcode
, street
, housenr
, nr_rel_a
, nr_rel_b
, date_modified
, name || ifnull(postcode, 'null') || ifnull(street, 'null') || ifnull(housenr, 'null') as unique_key
from table_name
qualify row_number() over (partition by unique_key order by nr_rel_a, date_modified) = 1


Thanks a lot for your contribution Courtney! If I get your idea, you create a combined field with the relevant information for the dup detection. I'll try that to see if it can detect all 3 abc's as dups. Thanks for your support!
